# When do purchasable upgrades take effect in Desktop Defender?

Tags: desktop-defender

In Desktop Defender, you can either upgrade a tower by spending money in game or by spending coins out of game (in the metagame).  When do the out of game upgrades take effect?  Do they affect level 1 towers, or do you have to upgrade those towers *in game* before they do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upgrade those towers in game; what the out-of-game upgrades do is basically unlock in-game tower ranks, but you must still upgrade in-game to the new rank.